# SQLite3 - Database is locked after UPDATE query

Tags: python, flask, sqlite, sql-update, pycharm

I have written the following piece of code within Flask to allow me to update the address of a particular user/patient stored. However once the form has been submitted I am presented with the error: 'sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
@app.route('/portal/<username>/edit', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def edit(username):

    logged_in_as = session['username']
    g.db = connect_db()
    cursor = g.db.cursor()
    if request.method == 'POST':
       cid = request.form['customerid']
       address = request.form['address']
       telephone = request.form['telephone']
       cursor.execute("""UPDATE customer SET address = ?, telephone = ? WHERE                    customer_id = ?""", (address, telephone, cid))
       g.db.commit()
       return redirect(url_for('customerportal'))
    sql = """SELECT customer.customer_id FROM customer JOIN users ON customer.user_id = users.userid WHERE users.username = (?)"""
    data = list(cursor.execute(sql, (username,)))
    return render_template('edit.html', data=data, username=logged_in_as)
```

Comment: you should really look at [sqlalchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) and [flask-sqlalchemy](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/) to integrate database work in python and specifically flask. Sqlalchemy is a high level abstraction of your database operations and the flask-sqlalchemy extension will allow elegant integration with flask.